# How to change the layout of the file upload field?

Tags: python, django

There is a standard for any form for file upload field. In Django, it is accompanied by additional functionality: the check-box for the destruction of the image, label field, which is now loaded, etc.

I would like to change the layout of this field. I.e. I need to know where is the template responsible for displaying the field and move it to where you can edit without affecting the core package.

Please tell me.

Comment: Are you talking about admin page templates ?

Comment: What you're looking for is a widget override, which is documented here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/